# Undefined index: winkelwagen_0022-T

Tags: php, mysql

I got this error undefined index. normally i know how to solve those errors except this one: looks like I forgot something somewhere???

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbcon.php';
$page = 'index.php';
if(isset($_GET['toevoegen'])){
$query ='SELECT partnr, hoeveelheid FROM producten WHERE partnr='.mysqli_real_escape_string($connectie,(int)$_GET['toevoegen']);
$result = mysqli_query($connectie, $query);
 while($result_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($result_row['hoeveelheid']!=$_SESSION['winkelwagen_'.$_GET['toevoegen']]){
        $_SESSION['winkelwagen_'.$_GET['toevoegen']]+='1';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Show us your full error message

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: winkelwagen_0106-FW in D:\Installaties\wamp\www\winkelwagentest\winkelwagen.php on line 9
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0004 253896 {main}( ) ..\winkelwagen.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: winkelwagen_0106-FW in D:\Installaties\wamp\www\winkelwagentest\winkelwagen.php on line 10
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0004 253896 {main}( ) ..\winkelwagen.php:0

Comment: `$_SESSION['winkelwagen_'.$_GET['toevoegen']]` is undefined

Comment: Looks like `$_SESSION['winkelwagen_...']` is not initialized.

Comment: Okay and where do i have to initialize this, tried everything haha

Comment: Define it before the while loop

Comment: hmm....keep getting the same error.